# WordPress non translatable content on a translatable custom post (via WPML)

Tags: wordpress, metadata, translation, meta-boxes, wpml

I was recently implementing a custom post type in WordPress, and added WPML so I could translate it's title & content.

This post type (city) also has some custom metaboxes (metabox.io) like:

- Coordinates
- isFeatured
- Address
- etc...

The problem I'm facing now is these custom fields get stored against the post ID, and need to be added for each language (different languages are different post ID's). This is neither convenient or practical, given that I must now duplicate all the values from these fields in each language, and if there's a mistake one same city may have different coordinates in different languages.

My question is, what would be the best way to tackle this problem? How can I have one set of metadata relate to all the translations of a same post?
This way I only need to add it once for each city, and edit it in one place if needed.

Thanks,

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll move it over.

Comment: It is here now: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181338/fixed-values-for-same-post-translations/214120#214120